# Show error message on Submit button if Radio Button is not clicked

Tags: javascript, razor

I need to show an error message if **No Radio Button** is selected in the Model Form. I am getting Values into the radio form and now want to show a message that "**Please select a Resume first**" if **no** **Resume** is selected.

Following is the code for Model form in which I am showing the **Radio Button**:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="ResumeModal" role="dialog" ng-controller="topCtrl">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content ">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ApplyJob", "PostedJob", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                          x
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Choose Your Resume</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="hidden" name="PostedJobId" id="PostedJobById" value="@Model.PostedJobId" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="CreatedBy" id="CreatedBy" value="@Model.CreatedBy" />
                            @foreach (var item in NurseOneStop.WebSite.Models.ApplicationSession.CurrentUser.NurseResumeList)
                            {
                                <div class="col-md-12 lstCard">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="CheckedResumeId" id="CheckedResumeId" />
                                    <input type="radio" name="RBCheckedResume" style="height: 15px; width: 18px;" onchange="CheckedResume(@item.ResumeId)" /> <span>@item.ResumeName</span>
                                     </div>
                            }
                        </div>

                        <span style="color:Red">{{msg}}</span>

                        @*<label id="lblMessage" style="color:red"></label>*@

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <span style="color:Red">{{msg}}</span>
                <button id="btnSubmitResume" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="userAlertResumeSubmit()">
                        Submit
                </button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the code for JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnShowModal").click(function (){
            $("#ResumeModal").modal('show');
        });
    });

    function CheckedResume(id) {
        $('#CheckedResumeId').val(id);
        console.log($('#CheckedResumeId').val());
    };



</script>
```

Comment: in which button click you want to check the radio button is checked or not ?

Comment: give an id to your radio button and then check using var isChecked = $('#radibuttonid').prop('checked'); this will give a Boolean values based on your radio button check status.

Comment: on your `button click` just put a check for the length of the radio buttons `checked`  as `$('input[name="RBCheckedResume"]:checked').length` if the `length` is equal to `0(zero)` show your message else let it pass.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it on a website recently. Please note, you should swap out the 'UIKit.notification' for something else if you are not using UIKit already on the website.

```
$('.btnSubmitResume').submit(function(e){


   if ($("input[name=RBCheckedResume]:checked").length === 0) {
    e.preventDefault();

    UIkit.notification({
        message: 'Please check at least one box to continue',
        status: 'primary',
        pos: 'top-right',
        timeout: 5000
    });
}
```

});

Also please note, you should not be using an ID within a for loop like id="CheckedResumeId". This will create multiple ID's of the same type and cause issues for you. I'd advise changing this to a class

Answer (score 0):

ID attribute for an HTML element should be unique. In the code snippet which you've shared, duplicate hidden form elements with ID 'CheckedResumeId' will be created which will pollute the HTML DOM. You can take the element outside of foreach and check the code. Like Below

```
<input type="hidden" name="CheckedResumeId" id="CheckedResumeId" />
@foreach (var item in NurseOneStop.WebSite.Models.ApplicationSession.CurrentUser.NurseResumeList)
    {
        <div class="col-md-12 lstCard">
            <input type="radio" name="RBCheckedResume" style="height: 15px; width: 18px;" onchange="CheckedResume(@item.ResumeId)" /> 
            <span>@item.ResumeName</span>
        </div>
    }
```

Here goes the JS to check if radio button is clicked when executing the onsubmit function.

```
if($('#CheckedResumeId').val().trim() == "") {
    //Give an error message to user saying that the radio button is not clicked.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. Also, I've tried the JS you have shared but it is not working. On Submit click, screen is redirected to a blank screen with url as http://localhost:49500/PostedJob/ApplyJob.

Comment: @JatinBhatia - A Form submit always redirects to the action page mentioned in the form tag. I cannot see the form element in the code shared. If action="", then it will redirect to same page, else it will go to the page specified in action. So what we have to do is, we have to first check for the radio button clicked. If clicked, then we have to "return false;" which will make sure that redirect wont happen
If you are passing the event also to the submit function, then you can call 'event.preventDefault()'

If this does not work, share the entire code as a JS bin link - https://jsbin.com

Comment: Never mind. I just added the keyword required inside the Input tag and there's a Default Message available now. Thanks

Comment: Kudos! That is the simplest solution :)